# Making a generic TypeEditor

Tags: c#, generics, uitypeeditor

Say I have a property `Foo` of type `SomeType` in a class of type `SomeClass` which is edited with a custom editor `SomeTypeEditor`:

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(SomeTypeEditor), ...)]
public SomeType Foo
{
    get
    {
        return BuildFooFromInternalRepresenation();
    }
    set
    {
        UpdateInternalRepresentation(value);
    }
}
```

The `SomeTypeEditor.EditValue` function looks something like this:

```
public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.IServiceProvider provider, object value)
{
    IWindowsFormsEditorService edSvc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
    if (null == edSvc)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var form = new SomeTypeEditorForm(value as SomeType);
    if (DialogResult.OK == edSvc.ShowDialog(form))
    {
        var someClass = context.Instance as SomeClass;
        someClass.Foo = form.Result;
        return someClass.Foo;
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I would now like to add another property `Baz`, also of type `SomeType`, to `SomeClass`. I would like to edit this property `SomeTypeEditor` but the line

```
someClass.Foo = form.Result;
```

in `EditValue` ties `SomeTypeEditor` to this particular property. It would be simple enough to just make a duplicate of `SomeTypeEditor` which edits `Baz` instead but I would like to avoid that if possible. Is there anyway to make my `SomeTypeEditor` generic (in any sense of the word) so it can be used to edit both `Foo` and `Baz`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that if I let `EditValue` return a different `object` than `value`, `set` will be invoked on the property from which the edit originated, so just doing:

```
if (DialogResult.OK == edSvc.ShowDialog(form))
{
    var someClass = context.Instance as SomeClass;
    return form.Result;
}
```

works (`SomeTypeEditor` clones the incoming value and edits the clone).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `provider` to get the name of the property being edited in the property grid. To see this set a break point on your editing routine `EditValu`e and then hover over the `provider` property. Expand it and you will see that it contains a property with the name of the Foo/Baz being edited. Not sure if this is the recommended way to obtain the information but it seems to work.

Comment: How can I invoke `set` on this property?